# I need to add the attribute tail to self, and tail should always be pointing at the last node in the list

Tags: python

The tail attribute should always be pointing at the last node in the list. When a list is initialized the tail should be set to None. I need to modify the append method to have a run time of O(1) rather than O(n). I should do this by adding a new node after the tail and moving the tail to the new node, but I confused on how to do actually write it.

**So my original code looked like this:**

```
class UnorderedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append(self, item):
        current = self.head
        if current:
            while current.get_next() != None:
                current = current.get_next()
            current.set_next(Node(item))
        else:
            self.head = Node(item)
```

**this was when I only head self.head as an attribute, self.head was always pointing to the first node in the linked list.
Now I have to add the tail attribute that is supposed to always point at the last node in the linked list. And I have to modify the append function so that it uses the tail attribute and instead of having a running time of O(n) it has one of O(1). So the end result should look something like this**

```
class UnorderedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def append(self, item):
        current = self.tail
        **code that adds the new node after the tail and moves the tail over to the new node or sets it equal to**
```

**My issue is I simply do not know how to change the functions within the UnorderedList class to fit the tail attribute, and need some help on how to do so.**

```
class Node:


    def __init__(self, node_data):
        self._data = node_data
        self._next = None

    def get_data(self):
    
        return self._data

    def set_data(self, node_data):
    
        self._data = node_data

    data = property(get_data, set_data)

    def get_next(self):
    
        return self._next

    def set_next(self, node_next):
    
        self._next = node_next

    next = property(get_next, set_next)

    def __str__(self):
    
        return str(self._data)

class UnorderedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head == None

    def add(self, item):
        temp = Node(item)
        temp.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = temp

    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current is not None:
            count = count + 1
            current = current.next

        return count

    def append(self, item):
        current = self.tail
        if current:
            while current.get_next() != None:
                current = current.get_next()
            current = current.set_next(Node(item))
        else:
            self.tail = Node(item)
        
        
    

    def search(self, item):
        current = self.head
        while current is not None:
            if current.data == item:
                return True
            current = current.next

        return False

    def remove(self, item):
        current = self.head
        previous = None

        while current is not None:
            if current.data == item:
                break
            previous = current
            current = current.next

        if current is None:
            raise ValueError("{} is not in the list".format(item))
        if previous is None:
            self.head = current.next
        else:
            previous.next = current.next

    def __str__(self):
        result = ""
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            result += str(node.data)
            result += " "
            node = node.next
        return result
            


def main():
    teststring()
    teststring2()
    testappend()
    testappend2()

def teststring():
    my_list = UnorderedList()
    my_list.add(31)
    my_list.add(77)
    my_list.add(17)
    my_list.add(93)
    my_list.add(26)
    my_list.add(54)
    print(my_list) # should print 54 26 93 17 77 31

def teststring2():
    my_list = UnorderedList()
    print(my_list) #should print nothing

def testappend():
    my_list = UnorderedList()
    my_list.add(31)
    my_list.add(77)
    my_list.add(17)
    my_list.add(93)
    my_list.add(26)
    my_list.add(54)
    my_list.append(51)
    my_list.append(22)
    print(my_list)#expected to print 54 26 93 17 77 31 51 22 

def testappend2():
    my_list = UnorderedList()
    my_list.append(34)
    print(my_list) # should print 34

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please could you clarify the problem, and see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, reproducible amount](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It would then be much easier to read.

Comment: i went back and clarified, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems the while loop in your append is no longer necessary because you will already be at the tail. So you can remove those two lines of code. The last thing you need to do is point the tail to the new node you're adding to the list. I've adjusted that code below:

```
def append(self, item):
    current = self.tail
    if current:
        current = current.set_next(Node(item))
        self.tail = current
    else:
        self.tail = Node(item)
```